# JavaScript object exists even if I do not initialize or set it to a value

Tags: jquery, javascript-objects, stringify

I have two functions, one function initializes the object and another does not:

This function is called on button click event and sends the object to  another function that will stringifies the object and have an Ajax call

```
function1(){

     var data = { ID: id, Amount: amount, Desc: desc, 
     title: desc, cUrl: url };

     ActionFunction(data)

}
```

In this functing I need to check if the `data1` object has data, and if it does, do some logic:

```
function ActionFunction(data1){

   if(data1 != null){
     //do somewthing
   }
   else{
     //do something else
   }
}
```

`ActionFunction` is called from another place without assigning anything to `data` And in that case, the `data1` in `ActionFunction` is not null as well.

Why is that? How do I perform a check to see if `data1` object has any data?

Comment: If `data1` is not null, that would suggest that the other place is also passing in a non-null value to the method.

Comment: U can check like this. If (data1.varianceId != null)

Answer (score 0):

You should always check for undefined as well.

```
function ActionFunction(data1){

   if(data1 != null || data1 != undefined){
     //do somewthing
   }
   else{
     //do something else
   }
}
```

Comment: or so long as data1 will not be a boolean, `!data1`

Comment: FYI, `data1 != null || data1 != undefined` is equivalent to just `data1 != null`.

Comment: undefined and null are two distinct types: undefined is a type itself (undefined) while null is an object.    JavaScript makes a special distinction here so that you can't compare. The reason null is equal to undefined is because of JavaScript's type system and equality checking. ... In JavaScript, both null and undefined have a falsy value so when you do an equality check with == they are considered the same. Thanks Felix, learning is fun.

Comment: Well, if that's the case, then this answer is effectively the same as what the OP is already doing.